# How to hide highlighted part from Xcode Storyboard image?

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode13

I am using Xcode 13. On storyboard I can see square view which quick access of the other controller. I have attached image and highlighted.
[image]

What do we call this highlighted part and How can we hide it?

Comment: one storyboard and this much view controllers? RIP storyboard...

Comment: @FahimParkar Yes, We have this much view controllers. If I am doing something wrong and you have better idea then please let me know.

Comment: use XIB files instead of storyboard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its called minimap, you can turn it off at the toolbar: `Editor` -> `Minimap`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the editor options on the right side of the navigation pane (above the editor area) and turn off Minimap.

[image]